# Should I conduct authorization (permissions checks) on api-gateway level or on resource server (protected microservice)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, api-gateway

There is legacy application with monolithic architecture, main goal is to refactor this application with microservices architecture style. Legacy application has complex security model, actually user can have multiple roles, each role can have multiple permissions, each permission can have multiple attributes. There was idea to use pattern where api-gateway acts as oauth2.0 client and secure all resources behind. In current setup, api-gateway run `authorization code flow` with scopes including `openid`, as result it recieves three main parts: `accessToken`, `idToken` and user `authorities` and store them under session cookie. Also, in current setup `Token Relay` filter is used to send `accessToken` to resources.

The are few questions:

1. Is it considered best practice to verify fine grainded permissions on resorce servers level (protected microservices) ? If yes, how to provide user `authorities`, because `Token Relay` provide only `accessToken` ?
2. Is there any reason to run `authorization code flow` with `openid` scope on api-gateway side ? If yes, in which cases it can bring a value ?

Answer (score 1):

**A1**

Fine grained authorization should be done in resource servers. This logic will evolve often and is best managed by API teams. Your legacy app (website?) seems to be acting as a resource server and doing a good job of this. See also [this recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76875505/how-to-additionally-secure-a-rest-service-that-is-already-using-an-oauth-2-0-acc/76881836#76881836) for how this can work across multiple APIs.

Authorization values used should derive from claims in the access token. Eg issue the user identity and role there. then look up secondary values. See this [example oauth filter](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthorizer.java#L38) and [this service logic class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/logic/services/CompanyService.java#L25) for one way to do that.

**A2**

Avoid triggering OIDC flows on the server side of API requests. This is a bad thing to do since it prevents mobile apps or single page apps or iframes from calling your APIs. The server then redirects a caller who should not be redirected, eg an Ajax reqest. A better option is to just return a 401 to clients when they do not have a valid token.

Instead, each client should manage its own authentication flow, by interacting with an authorization server (AS). For web clients, a backend for frontend is often the client. This is distinct from an API. The client always triggers its own OIDC flow, leading to the cleanest separation. with best results for both apps and teams.

**GATEWAY ROLE**

The API gateway is a great place to deal with client specific security differences during API requests. A good gateway can run plugins that can execute custom security logic. You should only occasionally need to redeploy or reconfigure the gateway, whereas APIs will change frequently.

One plugin use case is for SPAs using secure cookies. The gateway can unwrap cookies, apply web specific security checks, eg for CORS and CSRF, then forward JWT access tokens to APIs. This keeps web concerns out of APIs, so that APIs are equally callable by all types of client.