# How to securely authorise user data following authentication

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I am currently researching authorisation and authentication for my Node.js / Express.js application.  In my scenario, I need to authenticate and identify a user, then retrieve data from my database that is associated with my user.

I learned about using Passport.js and express-sessions for authentication, and currently plan on using a local passport strategy to authenticate my users, but was wondering if I need to implement some kind of authorisation for my application to make it more secure. For instance, is simply associating a user id to each username / password combination fine, and then using that to query my database for associated data? I was primarily confused about this after reading up on OAuth(), which utilising third party authentication to recieve access tokens to then access resources from a resource server. I was unsure whether I needed something like this to maintain security, but I feel like I may be fundamentally misunderstanding how access tokens are used. Are they only used on external apis?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In any secured backend you need an unforgeable backend message credential that can be sent in HTTP requests, which identifies the user. You then need to implement authorization, to restrict access based on the user identity received. Eg in an online retail app, this would prevent user A from seeing user B's orders.

OAuth 2.0 is an authorization framework, widely used in both first-party and third-party use cases. Its main focus is the API message credential, called the access token. This conveys a user identity and can be locked down in various ways, using scopes and claims. It can be used by any API client, including web and mobile. Different API privileges can be granted to different clients.

There is a learning curve to OAuth, so you may be able to use a simpler solution for your current project. OAuth benefits become most apparent in larger setups, with multiple APIs and client applications. See [this recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76875505/how-to-additionally-secure-a-rest-service-that-is-already-using-an-oauth-2-0-acc/76881836#76881836) for an example of how the framework might be applied.

When using OAuth, a central component called the authorization server issues the access token. To see how the components in an OAuth end-to-end solution fit together, one option is to run my [initial code sample](https://authguidance.com/basicspa-overview/) tutorial.